# Getting mysql-simple to work on OSX (Haskell)

Tags: mysql, macos, haskell

Does anybody know how to get the mysql-simple library to run on OSX?  I get the following error:

Loading package mysql-0.1.1.4 ... can't load .so/.DLL for: libmysqlclient.dylib (dlopen(libmysqlclient.dylib, 9): no suitable image found. Did find:
/usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture)

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 1):

Well it sure sounds like you have the wrong MySQL lib, try running (from terminal): 
`file /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.dylib`
 it will probably be 32-bit while you are using 64-bit Haskell, or visa versa